# how create cron command

Tags: linux, unix, cron

how can i call some url like stackoverflow.com from cron without getting return data from page?

Comment: These are two question: 1. How to create a cron job. 2. How to access a website.

Comment: just out of interest, may I ask why? What will this achieve? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this:

wget --spider http://www.stackoverflow.com > /dev/null 2>&1

This command calls the url but doesnt download the output and redirect stderr and stdout to /dev/null

Answer (score 6):

The format for cron is as follows:

```
# Minute   Hour   Day of Month       Month          Day of Week        Command    
# (0-59)  (0-23)     (1-31)    (1-12 or Jan-Dec)  (0-6 or Sun-Sat)
```

For example, a cron to run at 9am every day and connect to a site would look like this:

```
0 9 * * * wget --spider http://www.stackoverflow.com > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Run `crontab -e` to edit the crontab, add this line to it and save.